# VSTS (VSO) Hosted Build .Net Framework 4.6.1

Tags: build, azure-devops

Does anyone know when the .Net Framework 4.6.1 will be supported on the hosted build controller within VSTS or VSO?

I've found information that it's not currently supported but none on when it's likely to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

4.6.1 came with VS 2015 QU2.

We are currently in the process of releasing a new image with that on it but we hit an image corruption issue with Azure.  It should have gone out a couple weeks ago but it's in a day for day slip.  Today, we got a workaround which we are trying.  I'll try and update here when it's on the image.  I'm hoping very soon.

Update:
We have an image produced and got past the corruption issue.  Testing and rolling through scale units.  Targeting Friday.

Comment: Just a meta-comment... why is the only source of this information is right here? Why isn't there a VSO blog entry or some sort of more official article about this? A little disappointing there's nothing about this other than here.

Comment: @Keith - communication was done through the official services blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsoservice/archive/2016/02/02/issues-with-xaml-builds-on-visual-studio-team-services-2-2-investigating.aspx

Comment: However, the progression usually ends up being, the community lights up on twitter, SO, etc..., we investigate, blog about it and fix.  So, even if we blog, you will always see on twitter and SO which is a good IMHO because those are channels that alot of people are on.

Comment: @bryanmac Do you have a status update on .net 4.6.1 support?

Comment: Seems to be working now.  The VSTS CI is succeeding.